# Failed to run AzureAD Module PowerShell commands inside windows container

Tags: powershell, docker, azure-active-directory

I am trying to run AzureAD Module PowerShell commands inside windows container but due its dependency with "IEFRAME.DLL" its throwing error

I also tried by copying dll inside container to windows system folder but it still complains

Is there any workaround or hack available to get it work inside windows container?

Comment: We can't use windows container in this way, you should use docker file to build new image with Azure AD powershell module(per-install).